# Expectation of Max/Min functions

Tags: probability-theory

Can $[(Q-X)^+\land\ q]^+$ be written as Max[Min(Max(Q-D,0),q),0).

If not, how can this be expressed? And how can the expected value of the E($[(Q-X)^+\land\ q]^+$) be derived, where X is a stochastic variable.
Thanks

Comment: Well, $[(Q-X)^+\wedge q]^+$ is indeed $\max[\min (\max[Q-X,0],q),0]$

Comment: Thanks, any suggestion on how I can derive the expected value of the function?

Comment: That depends on what are $Q$ and $q$.

Answer (score 0):

$[(Q-X)^+\wedge q]^+$ is indeed $\max[\min (\max[Q-X,0],q),0]$

Which will also be $\max[\min[Q-X,q],0]$

$$[(Q-X)^+\wedge q]^+=\begin{cases}q &:& \max[0,Q-X]< q\\ Q-X &:& \max[0,q]\leqslant Q-X\\0 &:& \max[q,Q-X]< 0\end{cases}$$

So $\begin{split}\mathsf E([(Q-X)^+\wedge q]^+) ~&=~ {{q~\mathsf P(0<q,Q-X<q)}+{\mathsf P(0<Q-X, q<Q-X)~\mathsf E(Q-X\mid 0<Q-X, q<Q-X)}}\end{split}$

Comment: I expanded it as 
$Min (Max (Q-X),q)$ = $\int_0^{Q-q} qdF(X)$ + $\int_{Q-q}^Q (Q-X)dF(X)$
and upon solving
$Min (Max (Q-X),q)$ = $\int_{Q-q}^Q F(X)dX$
Is this correct?